# How do you deal with relative imports in a contract you depend on?

Tags: solidity, remix

### Goal

I am attempting to create a smart contract that uses contracts from the [iden3](https://github.com/iden3/contracts) library. I am using the Remix IDE.

### Problem

My issue is that the contract I need (`IdentityBase.sol`) has several relative dependencies:

```
import {IOnchainCredentialStatusResolver} from "../interfaces/IOnchainCredentialStatusResolver.sol";
import {IState} from "../interfaces/IState.sol";
import {IdentityLib} from "../lib/IdentityLib.sol";
import {SmtLib} from "../lib/SmtLib.sol";

// /**
//  * @dev Contract managing onchain identity
//  */
abstract contract IdentityBase is IOnchainCredentialStatusResolver {
...
```

When I try to compile my custom Contract (`BasicContract.sol`), I see a bunch of errors related to these relative imports. For example:

```
ParserError: Source "@iden3/contracts/lib/SmtLib.sol" not found: Deferred import
 --> @iden3/contracts/lib/IdentityLib.sol:5:1:
  |
5 | import {SmtLib} from "../lib/SmtLib.sol";
```

In other words, the error seems to be occurring when the compiler is looking for these nested, relative imports.
[image]

How can I import these contracts?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be unrelated to the relative imports.

The issue was that the first import in my list (openzeppelin) was using the wrong compiler version.

I changed this:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
```

To this ([source](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import.html#import-from-npm)):

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable@4.9.3/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
```

Once this was fixed, all of the other compiler errors went away. This seems like a tricky Remix bug.